# ionic + anguular ng-bind-html is not working

Tags: angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework, html-rendering

I have fetched json webservice one of its field contain HTML tags
actually web service has `&lt;` & `&gt;` my code looks like

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','ngSanitize'])

 .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

 .controller('DetailCtrl', ['$sce','$scope',    '$stateParams','Chats',function($sce,$scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
   $scope.exe = Chats.detail($stateParams.exeId,$stateParams.sub_exeId);
    $scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
    {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
    };
 }])

 //also tried the following filter
  .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
   };
 }])
```

at my view I tried the following variations

```
<p ng-bind-html="exe.tips.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>')  | to_trusted"></p>

 <p ng-bind-html="exe.tips  | to_trusted"></p>

 <p ng-bind-html="exe.tips"></p>

 <p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(exe.tips)"></p>
```

and tried many other thing but still getting rendered the HTML
at view source it is like this `<p>"<ol><li>text</li>....`